# Are there mobile apps for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, mobile-web

I am used to using my smart phone to browse Stack Overflow with a web browser, but I feel that that's not a very good solution. Now I want to use a mobile app to browse SO.

Is there a mobile app for Stack Overflow, or plans to develop one? Third-party apps (both Android and iOS) would be fine for me.

Comment: sorry, i ask in the wrong place?

Comment: Yes, but it's been moved to the right place now.  But what do you think an app would add that the mobile site lacks?

Comment: better user experience, i think.

Comment: What part of the "user experience?"  Just the fact that you open it from the home screen?

Comment: for example, i can't format my answers to a elegant style

Comment: Sure you can, I do it quite often.  You just need to know how to do it without the buttons.  And you're just as unlikely to get the buttons in a mobile app.

Comment: good advice,i am so stupid.

Comment: Come on, all you have to do is go to the respective marketplaces and search for "stackoverflow".  And, by the rate of ios/android questions, I'm sure this list will be stale in about two minutes.

Comment: @macskuz Don't be so hard on yourself =)  I thought the same thing before I got used to the mobile interface.

Comment: There will be. Official Android app is under active development. This comment is posted with the closed alpha version.

Comment: To be able to have notifications on your mobile / tablet would be nice...

Comment: http://stackapps.com/ shows all the available apps for stackoverflow ranging from mobile app to extensions for the browsers of desktop

Comment: Try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jentsch.it42 android app