# Mobile App for Stackoverlfow

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there mobile apps for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/are-there-mobile-apps-for-stack-overflow)

Does Stack Overflow have a mobile application?

I mean a smartphone app for iOS, Android or Windows Phone?

Comment: Stackapps has some that users have made http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/iphone+app

Comment: And for Android there is [Droidstack](http://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-now-with-chat-support)

Answer (score 2):

There is a mobile view of the website you can access [here](https://stackoverflow.com/?__=792041428)

But there is no official app.

Comment: And no app that supports logging in beyond notifications.

Comment: @Manishearth - yep, Droidstack does.

Comment: @Rory wait.. It does?? Mine doesn't... Will root around a bit and see if I can find the login option

Comment: check out some of the info on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/are-there-mobile-apps-for-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

Droidstack works really well on Android - it supports full logging in, and copes well with chat. I use it for my main SE sites when on the go.

Its only glitch is when trying to migrate - the options given are not selectable, but that isn't a major issue.